# String as Primary Key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I know this has been discussed a lot, and my final choice is: I will use string as primary key, mainly for two reasons:

1. I won't have more than 100k rows
2. It will simplify a lot

Is there anything I can do to improve performance, like creating a index?

I'm using Entity Framework code-first.

Comment: Primary Key gets an index by default.

Comment: I read that this is bad idea, since the index building is more expensive than if it was integer. I really dont know to be honest. My fear is the performance, 100k rows is a number that I calculated with very very high expectations

Comment: Do you have performance problem with your current design on the data set that represent your extreme "100K rows" case? If you did not measure yet - set goals and do measurments now, when you have results - decide if they meet your goal. Only than start worrying - it likely will be easier to re-design DB later when you know what need to be stored.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I will give some try, and comeback later.

Comment: It's interesting that you think it will simplify things.  The main purpose of a primary key is to uniquely identify a record.  UUID and integer autoincrement make this very simple.  Yet you think creating 100000 unique strings will be simpler?  Good luck with that.

Comment: In this question you can see the type of information that will be used: [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108413/storing-relational-information), as I said they are natural keys, so when a user needs a view, we cant create anyone with the same name, so it is a natural path building. And the 100k was a extra large estimate.

Answer (score 4):

Creating an index is unnecessary, as the `PRIMARY KEY` provides a `UNIQUE`, `CLUSTERED` index.

Also note, most RDBMS have can more efficiently index fixed-length fields, such as `CHAR`, vs. variable length fields like `VARCHAR`.

One other possibility to consider:
An integer (`INT`) primary key, with a unique index on the string value that you were originally going to use as the `PRIMARY KEY`.  This provides the ease of `JOIN`ing on an integer field (not to mention space savings), while enforcing your original requirement.

Comment: I cannot have auto identity(or computed primary keys because I have to move identical information from one base to another over the web. With natural primary keys, I can do this without adding more complexity to my code.

Comment: What is the problem with the same data, surrogate key and all, from existing in duplicate on more than one "base"? Does everything get dumped into one central database from which queries will be run?

Comment: The information goes through this path: Development -> Testing -> Production -> Clients. The idea is that I can have the same data state in all these places. Sure, I can work with identity primary key, but it is not so good as making things simple and easier. How would things be easier ? I wont need to care about of existing relationships, I can just insert my objects or update, yet I will have to do a little of checking, but it would be more complex with surrogate keys.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the length of the `VARCHAR` as much as possible.

Indexes are automatically created for `PRIMARY KEYS`, so you don't have to create any index for this column.

Comment: Sorry, I posted a comment above. Please, take in consideration and update your answer if needed